# how many bytes does a string object in memory,contains the object header?

Tags: java, memory

As i know,a Java object contains object header,reference and it's data.

```
//jdk 1.7
public final class String{
       private final char value[];
       private int hash;
       //...
    }
```

For `new String("abc")` ,how many bytes will it take if we just think about 32-bit system?

```
totleBytes = 
    8//String Object header
    +4 //value reference 
    +4 //hash
    +12 //char[] object header
    +3*1//value[] data
```

does it right,or miss something?

Comment: Java uses UTF-16 internally, so the char data itself would be 6 bytes in the given example, and generally varies from multiples of length since UTF-16 uses variable-length encoding.

Comment: Have a look at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/